# Main component not showing other components

Tags: angular

I created a very simple basic angular 4 application which is just using a basic directive, service and 2-3 components. Somehow the main component html page is showing up but it includes other components which are not showing up.

Code is at the location : https://github.com/payalbnsl/angula4_basic.git

Comment: Are there any errors showing up?

Comment: No errors, only on webpage , only 1 component showing up

Comment: It takes a minute to open up this code in visual studio and do compile and see the output : @omeralper

Comment: If you want to show your code, use plunkr or stackblitz. otherwise post your problematic code.

Comment: I just cloned and checked your project. You might want to check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not put any HTML tags inside `<p> </p>.` If you remove your P tags from mycomponent.component.html and servercomponent.component.html file as below, the app should work just fine.

```
<p>In server component html page!</p>
```

Also, if you are using IE, please uncomment below lines from polyfills.ts file

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Comment: P is also an html tag. Why not to use it?

Comment: However uncommenting code in polyfill.ts got it working. Thanks!